# Two experiments with shared control, can I generalize?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test

I have run two experiments, let's say the control condition is A. The two treatment conditions are B and C. I determined that B < A on some variable, and that C > A on that same variable. These were determined in two separate experiments. Can I now say that B < A < C?

Comment: So you had one sample whose subjects were subjected (subsequently or by cross over) to treatment A and B and another sample whose subjects got treatment A and C, right? Are you sure that the subjects of both samples are similar in baseline?

Comment: Well, they're both taken from the same sample pool, but at different time periods (e.g., 1 month apart). Subjects were only in 1 experiment or the other.

Comment: You really need to add details for this to be answerable in other than generalities